# How to choose between mpir and mpfr

Tags: c++, c, windows, bigdata, mpfr

I need to make some calculations with huge numbers, and I need it to be done very efficiently and fast. Most of the numbers are integers but at the end I divide two of them to get a rational number, which I can use a double to hold.

I use Microsoft Visual Studio (on Windows, to program c++ or c) so as I understand, MPIR is the best choice. But maybe MPFR is better for my needs? When should I choose MPFR and when MPIR?

Thanks!

Comment: How large is the project? After recently porting my computation engine to MPFR recently, I can tell you that MPFR and other arbitrary-precision libraries are only for _very_ large projects that _need_ the  precise computation.

Comment: The biggest number is (10000!). I need the computations to be pretty precise. The final answer which is a division of two big integers should be less than 10^-10 away from the true answer.

How big are the numbers that MPFR can deal with?

Comment: MPFR is an arbitrary precision library, which means the precision of the numbers is limited to RAM.

Comment: I think that's enough. Does MPIR have the same limit? Thanks!